# Seit letzten April oder Seit letztem April?

Tags: dative

In einem Lehrbuch habe ich folgende Konstruktion gefunden: "seit letzten April". Auch die Google-Suche liefert viele solche Ergebnisse. In allen Nachschlagewerken, die ich hierzu konsultierte, steht jedoch, dass diese Präposition den Dativ verlangt. Deshalb möchte ich gerne wissen, ob Konstruktionen wie "seit letzten April" oder "seit letzten Freitag" falsch sind, oder ob die Präposition "seit" auch mit Akkusativ stehen kann (gerne mit Quelle).

Vielen Dank.

Comment: Zitiere bitte immer vollständige Sätze oder (falls das nicht möglich ist) einen etwas längeren Textausschnitt.

Comment: Interessanterweise ist diese schleichende Veränderung m -> n meist bei den männlichen Zeitangaben zu hören, insbesondere bei
den männlichen Monaten, aber das "r" bei den weiblichen Formen (seit letzter Nacht, seit vergangener Woche, seit dieser Zeit, seit dieser Versammlung,...) ist von dieser Erosion weniger betroffen. Ich habe allerdings auch schon "seit letzte Nacht" gehört....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wir brauchen in Deinem Beispiel den Dativ, weil die Präposition "seit" immer den Dativ verlangt.

Hättest Du keine Präposition, wäre der Akusativ korrekt:

```
Letzten April bin ich nach Kiribati geflogen.
```

Zu Deinem Lehrbuch kann ich nichts sagen, aber nur weil Du bei Google viele Treffer findest, heißt das bestenfalls, dass hier bei den Deutschen selbst Unsicherheit herrscht. Wenn sich das ausbreitet, entscheidet die Duden-Redaktion vielleicht in 50 Jahren, dass man "seit" auch mit Akusativ verwenden darf, weil das allgemeiner Gebrauch geworden ist.